# Запрет одновременного запуска нескольких таймеров

Tags: javascript, reactjs, таймер

Добрый вечер.

В данный момент выполняю задание, где столкнулась со сложностью. У меня есть to-do list с возможностью тайм-трекинга задачи. 
Суть проблемы в том, чтобы пользователь может выполнять только одну программу одновременно, т.е. он должен запустить таймер только одной задачи и в это время кнопки на других таймерах - неактивны для запуска.

Вот мой код, подозреваю, что проблема в setState, но не могу разобраться до конца. Таймеры появляются, работают, но продолжают работать одновременно при каждом нажатии на старт.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import classnames from 'classnames'
import TodoTextInput from './TodoTextInput'

export default class TodoItem extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { secondsStart: this.props.minSeconds, timerRunning: false }
  }

    static propTypes = {
    todo: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    deleteTodo: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    completeTodo: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }

  static defaultProps = {
      minSeconds: 0
  }
  handleSave = (id, text) => {
    if (text.length === 0) {
      this.props.deleteTodo(id)
    }
  }

handleStartClick = () => {
    if (!this.state.timerRunning) {
      this.incrementer = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState({
          secondsStart: (this.state.secondsStart + 1)
        });
      }, 1000)
      this.setState({
        timerRunning: true,
        currentTodoId: this.props.todo.id,
        runningTodoId: this.props.todo.id
      });
    }
  }


  getSeconds = () => {
    return ('0' + this.state.secondsStart % 60).slice(-2)
  }

   getMinutes = () => {
    return Math.floor((this.state.secondsStart / 60)%60)
  }
    getHoures = () => {
    return Math.floor((this.state.secondsStart / 3600)%24)
  }


  handleStopClick = () => {
    clearInterval(this.incrementer)
    this.setState({ timerRunning: false, currentTodoId: null, runningTodoId: null });
  }

  render() {
  const { todo, completeTodo, deleteTodo} = this.props

  const element = this.state.todo ? (
      <TodoTextInput text={todo.text}
        onSave={(text) => this.handleSave(todo.id, text)} />
    ) : (
        <div className="view">
          <input className="toggle"
            type="checkbox"
            checked={todo.completed}
            onChange={() => completeTodo(todo.isRequired)} />
          <label>
            {todo.text}
          </label>
          <div className="buttons">
            <h6>{this.getHoures()}:{this.getMinutes()}:{this.getSeconds()}</h6>
            {(this.state.secondsStart === 0)
              ? <button className="timer-start" onClick={this.handleStartClick} disabled={this.state.timerRunning }>Start</button>
              : <button className="timer-stop" onClick={this.handleStopClick} disabled={!this.state.timerRunning && this.state.runningTodoId !== this.state.currentTodoId}>Stop</button>
            }
          </div>
          <button className="destroy"
            onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.id)} />
        </div>
      )

    return (
      <li className={classnames({
        completed: todo.completed,
      })}>
        {element}
      </li>
    )
  }
}
```

Также отмечу, что у TodoItem есть родитель - TodoTextInput, через который генерируются мои Items и я думала, что возможно таймер нужно было генерировать оттуда, но всё-таки решение выше мне ближе.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Данный вопрос был решен.
Необходимо было корректно связать родительский элемент и дочерний.

*Изменение в дочернем компоненте:*

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import classnames from 'classnames'
import moment from 'react-moment'


let interval;

export default class TodoItem extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    todo: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    deleteTodo: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    completeTodo: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

  handleDeleteClick = () => {
    this.props.deleteTodo(this.props.todo.id);
  }


  handleStartClick = () => {
    this.props.startTimer(this.props.todo.id);
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.props.updateTimer(this.props.todo.id);
    }, 1000);
  }


  handleStopClick = () => {
    this.props.stopTimer(this.props.todo.id);
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

  handleCompleteClick = () => {
    this.props.completeTodo(this.props.todo.id);
    this.props.stopTimer(this.props.todo.id);
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

  render() {
    const { todo, timerActive, timerTodo } = this.props

    return (
      <li className={classnames({
        completed: todo.completed
      })}>
        <div className="view" style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }} onClick={this.handleSelectToDo}>
          <input
            className="toggle"
            type="checkbox"
            checked={todo.completed}
            onChange={this.handleCompleteClick}
          />
          <label style={{ width: '40%' }}>
            {todo.text}
          </label>
          <span style={{ display: 'block', fontSize: 16 }}>Time is {todo.total}</span>
          {(!timerActive || timerTodo === todo.id) && (
            <button
              style={{
                background: 'transparent',
                border: 0,
                outline: 0,
                fontSize: 12,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                marginLeft: 30
              }}
              disabled={timerActive && timerTodo !== todo.id}
              onClick={timerActive ? this.handleStopClick : this.handleStartClick}
            >{timerActive ? 'Stop' : 'Start'}</button>
          )}
          <button className="destroy" onClick={this.handleDeleteClick} />
        </div>
      </li>
    )
  }
}
```

*Изменение в родительском компоненте:*

```
 return (
      <section className="main">

        <ul className="todo-list">
          {todos.map(todo =>
            <TodoItem key={todo.id} todo={todo} {...actions} timerActive={timerActive} timerTodo={timerTodo} todototal={todo.total}/>
          )}
        </ul>
        {this.renderFooter(completedCount)}
      </section>
    )
```

*Редьюсеры:*

```
case START_TIMER: {
  const todo = { ...state.todos.find(item => item.id === action.id) };
  todo.startTime = new Date();
  const todos = [...state.todos].map(item => item.id === action.id ? todo : item);
  return { ...state, timerActive: true, timerTodo: action.id, todos };
}
case STOP_TIMER: {
  return { ...state, timerActive: false, timerTodo: null }
}
case UPDATE_TODO_TOTAL: {
  const todo = { ...state.todos.find(item => item.id === action.id) };
  todo.total += 1;
  const todos = [...state.todos].map(item => item.id === action.id ? todo : item);
  const total = state.total || 0;
  return { ...state, todos, total: total + 1 };
}
```

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/144875)

Comment: @Vadizar, какое дополнение? Это не дополнение к вопросу. Она написала, что решила свою задачу и написала, как именно

Comment: Дополните ваш ответ более развёрнутым описанием решения или кодом. Сейчас ваш ответ выглядит, как комментарий.

Comment: @Yuri, ответ дополнен примером внесенных изменений в код.

Comment: @ValeriaShpiner, отлично! :)